# Join 3 tables, Create new Row if Unique

Tags: sql, laravel

I have three tables that I'm trying to join.

I join the first two:

```
Purchase Orders
+-----+----------+
| ID  | location |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | Canada   |
| 2   | USA      |
+-----+----------+

Stock
+-----+----------+----------------+
| SKU | OnOrder  |PurchaseOrderID |
+-----+----------+----------------+
| ABC | 30       |2               |
| DEF | 40       |1               |
+-----+----------+----------------+
```

And my result is:

```
+-----+----------+----------------+
| SKU | OnOrder  |location        |
+-----+----------+----------------+
| ABC | 30       |USA             |
| DEF | 40       |Canada          |
+-----+----------+----------------+
```

And now I want to join this result with another table as shown below

```
ItemOrders
+-----+----------+----------------+
| SKU | Quantity |Location        |
+-----+----------+----------------+
| ABC | 88       |USA             |
| DEF | 99       |Mexico          |
+-----+----------+----------------+
```

Where:

location of Join1 equals location of Table 3, and
SKU of Join 1 equals Table 3 .

If the match doesn't exist, it should make a new row

So I want my output to be:

```
+-----+----------+--------------------------+
| SKU | OnOrder  |Quantity |Location        |
+-----+----------+---------+----------------+
| ABC | 30       |88       |USA             |
| DEF | 40       |         |Canada          |
| DEF |          |99       |Mexico          |
+-----+----------+---------+----------------+
```

I really can't wrap my head around this for some reason. I've tried two joins, a merge, two joins and a union. I'm trying to do this in laravel FWIW.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would create 2 queries where both return the same columns and then UNION them together.

Wrap that entire thing in a subquery and GROUP BY SKU, Location and use an aggregate function as a way to aggregate the 2 rows into one.

Aggregate functions usually ignore Null values so simply a MAX() might work.

Like,

```
SELECT SKU, Location, max(OnOrder) as OnOrder, max(Quantity) as Quantity
FROM 
(
SELECT SKU, OnOrder, NULL as Quantity, Location
FROM {stuff to build output 1}

UNION ALL

SELECT SKU, NULL as OnOrder, Quantity, Location
FROM {stuff to build output 2}

) rs
GROUP BY SKU, Location;
```